# Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "try-error"

Tags: r

I have a question that I know many times answered in this page, I tried all of them but unfortunately any of them did not work for me. I am pretty new in R and I read a lot but I could not find the answer. I really appreciate if anybody can help me.

I put my code here  the error is " Error in UseMethod("meta", x) :    no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "try-error" "

here is my code,

```
#init

libs <- c("tm" , "plyr" , "class", "wordcloud", "SnowballC" )
lapply(libs, require, character.only = TRUE)

#set options
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#set parameters
candidates <- c("obama","romney")
pathname <- "/home/sahar/R/sample-text/speeches"

#clean text
cleancorpus <- function(corpus)
{

        corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers, lazy = TRUE)
        print( corpus.tmp)
        corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus, removepunctuation, lazy = TRUE)
        print( corpus.tmp)
        corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stripwhitespace, lazy = TRUE )
        print( corpus.tmp)
        corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, content_transformer(tolower), lazy = TRUE)
        print( corpus.tmp)
        #corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, tolower)
     # corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, PlainTextDocument)
        corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, removewords, stopwords("english"), lazy = TRUE)
        print( corpus.tmp)
        corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stemDocument, lazy = TRUE)
        print( corpus.tmp)
       # corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp, content_transformer(tolower(x) iconv(x, to='UTF-8-MAC', sub='byte')),  mc.cores=1)
       # wordcloud(corpus.tmp)
        return(corpus.tmp) 
}

#build TDM
generateTDM <- function(cand, path)
{
        s.dir <- sprintf("%s/%s" , path, cand)
       # s.cor <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = s.dir, encoding = "ANSI"))
        print(s.dir)
        s.cor <- VCorpus(DirSource(directory = s.dir), readerControl = list(reader = readPlain))
        print(s.cor)
#         s.cor <- tm_map(s.cor,
#                                       content_transformer(function(x) iconv(x, to='UTF-8-MAC', sub='byte')),
#                                       mc.cores=1
#         )

        s.cor.cl <- cleancorpus(s.cor)
        print(s.cor.cl)
        s.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(s.cor.cl)
        print(s.tdm)
        s.tdm <- removeSparseTerms(s.tdm, 0.7)
        print(s.tdm)
        result <- list(name = cand, tdm = s.tdm)
}


tdm <- lapply(candidates, generateTDM, path = pathname)
```

Comment: Post the full error message if there is more to it. Also post the results of `traceback()`. The dispatch can't find a method for `class(try-error)`, which is an output from a `try` statement when the expression fails to evaluate. Your code doesn't have a `try` in it, so it has to be buried in one of the functions you called.

Comment: It might not resolve your problem, but I think that the third line in your function should be `corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, removepunctuation, lazy = TRUE)`, with `corpus.tmp` instead of `corpus`.

Comment: @Vlo there is not any other error I just received some warning          Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "try-error"
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mclapply(x$content[i], function(d) tm_reduce(d, x$lazy$maps)) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
2: In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code

Comment: @Vlo                                                                                                       12: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
11: lapply(x, meta, tag)
10: meta.VCorpus(x, "id", "local")
9: meta(x, "id", "local")
8: TermDocumentMatrix.VCorpus(s.cor.cl)
7: TermDocumentMatrix(s.cor.cl) at document-classify.R#51
6: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
5: lapply(candidates, generateTDM, path = pathname) at document-classify.R#59
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("~/R/document-classify.R")

Comment: @RHertel thank you, you are right but as you think it did not change anythings